# Filter one by one using java stream

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

Sample json

```
"listProductDescription": [
            {
                "requestChannel": "MBA",
                "locale": "ENG",
                "shortDescription": "1 GB",
                "longDescription": "1 GB"
            },
            {
                "requestChannel": "MBA",
                "locale": "SIN",
                "shortDescription": "1 GB",
                "longDescription": "1 GB"
            },
            {
                "requestChannel": "MBA",
                "locale": "TAM",
                "shortDescription": "1 GB",
                "longDescription": "1 GB"
            }
        ]
```

Mapping class

```
public class ProductDescription{
  private String shortDescription;
  private String longDescription;
  private String requestChannel;
  private String locale;
 }

private List<ProductDescription> listProductDescription;
```

I want filter requestChannel = "MBA" and "local" = "TAM" object. If there is no record need to retrieve requestChannel = "MBA" and "local" = "ENG" object. How to do that with stream,
tried below but no success.

```
ProductDescription productDescription = productsDisplayInfo.getListProductDescription().stream()
            .filter(productDescription -> productDescription.getLocale().equals("TAM") && productDescription.getRequestChannel().equals("MBA"))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(productsDisplayInfo.getListProductDescription().stream()
                    .filter(productDescription -> productDescription.getLocale().equals("ENG") && productDescription.getRequestChannel().equals("MBA"))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("couldn,t find the value")));
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Refer to this [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/rnG). Note that if I change "TAM" to "TAX", the code also works.

Comment: Note that my code does not parse the JSON. Maybe your problem is there?

Answer (score 0):

After using `orElseGet` instead of `orElse` issue sorted.

```
ProductDescription productDescription = productsDisplayInfo.getListProductDescription().stream()
        .filter(productDescription -> productDescription.getLocale().equals("TAM") && productDescription.getRequestChannel().equals("MBA"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(() -> productsDisplayInfo.getListProductDescription().stream()
                .filter(productDescription -> productDescription.getLocale().equals("ENG") && productDescription.getRequestChannel().equals("MBA"))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("couldn,t find the value")));
```